# Vertical text in a Horizontal UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, uibutton, vertical-alignment

I'm using a vertical UIButton in a portrait app (Just a normal button that is of width 60 and Height 160)

I want to put the label Vetically down the button instead of across it.

When I use the following code to rotate the label

```
    [workPackageButton.titleLabel setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
```

It rotates the label but the length seems to be constrained by the original width, so I get the ... abreviation in the middle. Is there an easy way round this?

Comment: See answer below using a subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a Label on button and rotate the label as below:

```
UILabel *lbl= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(button.frame.size.width*.3, button.frame.size.height*.5, button.frame.size.width,button.frame.size.height)];
lbl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
lbl.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
[button addSubview:lbl];
```

Comment: when you do this, will it be possible to interact to the button?

Comment: i tried but the frame values doesnt match, i tried CGRectMake(0, 0, button.frame.size.height,button.frame.size.weight) it stays closer than before..

Comment: Actually i used like this way.
 lblC= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(button.frame.size.width*.39, button.frame.size.height*.50, button.frame.size.width*.7,button.frame.size.height/5)];
lblC.backgroundColor =[UIColor yellowColor];
lblC.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(38));
[button addSubview:lblC];

Comment: Thanks This works great. (Though I stuck with M_PI /2)
Cheers for the help.

:)

Comment: Update:

This worked the first time I use it. But the second time I use it I get an internal inconsistency error with AutoLayout

----->>
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Autolayout doesn't support crossing rotational bounds transforms with edge layout constraints, such as right, left, top, bottom. The offending view is: 
-----<<

And when I turn off AutoLayout options in the storyboard. My original code works just fine...

So now I'm lost. But this is just an update in case anyone find themselves in the same place.....

ArQ

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but another way to do this is to subclass the button and specify a square size for the button label.

```
@interface RotatingButton : UIButton

@end


@implementation RotatingButton

- (CGRect) titleRectForContentRect:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect frame = [super titleRectForContentRect:bounds];

    frame.origin.y -= (frame.size.width - frame.size.height) / 2;
    frame.size.height = frame.size.width;

    return frame;
}

@end
```

The label of any RotatingButton created in code or on Storyboard can be rotated without being truncated.

```
[button.titleLabel setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
```

Comment: i used this for full size label in my button        frame.origin.y = 0
        frame.size.height = self.bounds.size.height;

Answer (score 1):

I add the same problem, for buttons in stack view
So I needed something dynamic

for Swift 4.2

```
class VerticalButton: UIButton {

    override func titleRect(forContentRect bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var frame: CGRect = super.titleRect(forContentRect: bounds)

        frame.origin.y = 0
        frame.size.height = bounds.size.height

        return frame
    }
}
```

```
extension UILabel {
    @IBInspectable
    var rotation: Int {
        get {
            return 0
        } set {
            let radians = CGFloat(CGFloat(Double.pi) * CGFloat(newValue) / CGFloat(180.0))
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians)
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
    let button = VerticalButton.init(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
    button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    button.titleLabel?.rotation = -90
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.

Comment: I add the same problem in swift, and it had take me a lot of time to find this solution. Rotate a label in a button can be tricky

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this, but have you tried creating the button as a horizontal button (160w x 60h) then rotating the whole button?

Comment: Ian. You'd like to think so. But it freaks every think when you try this approach (this is where I started)..... 

:)

Answer (score 0):

For an easy way round do the following settings for the button in the Attributes inspector:

- Type: Custom
- Title: Attributed

Next, select left/middle/right or justified alignment. Do not use 'Align Natural'.

Now

```
[workPackageButton.titleLabel setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
```

works as expected with the label not being abreviated (but always being center aligned ...).

Tested with XCode 6.3.