# UIButton title label transform cuts off label

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am creating a UIButton with interface builder of size 30px width and 164px height.

I want to rotate title of UIButton to 90 degrees.

I am using following code for rotation

```
// leftNavBtn1 is a UIButton
self.leftNavBtn1.titleLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2);
```

The problem is after rotation the label cuts off. I have tried to programatically set title but its not work.

I want to achieve like this

[image]

What i am getting

[image]

Comment: I think you can try to make button with 164px width and 30 px heght, and make transform on all button, not only on label

Comment: Its easy for me to set buttons in interface builder, so i want to rotate button's label not the entire button.

Comment: did you try to set titleLabels frame directly after transformation (or bounds, edge insets) ?

Comment: Yes i have tried setting frame as well as setting label after transformation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230567/vertical-text-in-a-horizontal-uibutton/25418536#25418536 for a solution using a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

The `titleLabel` property is primarily used to configure the text of the button, not its bounds.

I don't think you can achieve what you want to achieve.
If I understand you correctly, you make a button with a small width and big height in interface builder, then set the transformation on the label of the button to 90º, and then expect the button to behave as if the width became the height and vice versa.

I suppose you could still set the button in interface builder, but make it horizontal, as if it's rotated -90º, and then set the transformation on the UIButton in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I am not expecting change in width and height of label, i am just expecting what transformation does, simply rotate at give angle.

Comment: @IrfanDANISH arguing semantics doesn't change the fact that a button that's not wide enough to hold your text, won't become wide by rotating its label. If you want a correct result, create a wide, horizontal button, and rotate the button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's stupid, but have you tried creating a label over your button and then apply the same rotation?

It's not elegant but can work